# Incorrect width calculated on resize

Tags: angular-ui-grid

i have an issue with ui-grid in angularJS, sometime at some resolution appear a gap like in above image 
[image]

PS: this issue appear when i try to resize the browser window

Comment: What version are you using? One of the recent RCs fixed this issue.

Comment: yes in 21, seems to be fixed, but this version has another issue with scroll, i try decorate  ($provide.decorator) grid factory to change function getViewportWidth, here seems to be the issue

Comment: So 21 fixes the issue described in this post, but you have a *different* issue now? If so, what is it specifically?

Comment: this module has a lot of issues, I redecorated a part of it and now seems to work